# Angular 4 single API request running multiple times

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-httpclient

I am having issue regarding Angular 4 App. I have created an app in which data is getting from third party APIs. The issue I am getting is my APIs are calling for multiple times but I sent request only once.

After some R&D I found browser is running flight request with OPTION method but after checking all APIs I found they are running for multiple times except flight request. Like fir an API I am requesting API once and it is running for 4 times 2 times for option and 2 times for GET request.I  check my code and only one time request is running.

I totally understand and agree with flight request.

I analyzed all the calls on my local and here is the finding:
1. all GET calls have corresponding OPTIONS call, which as per some artcle is not a problem
2. However, there are multiple calls for these:

```
http://localhost:3005/tasks?taskID=1713&singular=1 = 4 Get call, 2 OPTIONS call  - why?
http://localhost:3003/resources/30/configs = 2 GET call, 1 OPTIONS call - why?
http://localhost:3003/resources/146/configs = 2 GET cal, 1 OPTIONS call - why?
http://localhost:3003/resources/30/settings = 2 GET call, 1 OPTIONS call - why?
http://localhost:3003/resources/146/settings = 2 GET call, 1 OPTIONS call - why?
```

These are the only calls where GET is multiple times. For all other calls, /environments, /settings, /admin,/currentevent,/currentshift.. get call is going only once.

```
return this.http.get(this.environment.SFDCServiceHost + 'getCurrentEvent?resourceId=' + id + '&singular=1', {headers: this._helperService.setRequestHeader(id)});
```

[image: Browser requests]

Comment: can you please elaborate on the placement of the call, in other words, where are you calling the API from? it's the small things that give hints in this case

Comment: I created a service where I am running all the APIs and storing data to my browser session. whenever app loads for first time it get data from API by using that service. After that I use local storage for other things

Comment: the thing i am suspecting now is that wherever you are calling the API from, doesn't run only once, that would explain it, that's why I am asking for the code

Comment: I encountered same issue once, it was something with my interceptor and mergeMap operator, check for those if you use some

Comment: @DmytroGrynets But I am having this issue with some selected request. I have around 7 APIs but issues is coming with 3 only. Other requests are running fine.

Comment: @LabibIsmaiel I checked the request by adding console.log above it and it is running only once. The API is running only at one place so if it is running muntiple times it should show console multiple value but it is showing only once. Below is my function  getTask(id) {
    return this.http.get(this.environment.TasksServiceHost + 'tasks?taskID=' + id + '&singular=1', {headers: this._helperService.setRequestHeader()});
  }

Comment: Please show us the code in context. If you refuse to show us the code, there's really not much that we can do to help.

You may think that you have given us sufficient information, but usually the reason that someone can't find a tough bug like this is that they are absolutely sure of an assumption that turns out to be incorrect.

So, giving more context may allow others to see past your assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There May be some issue with your code. Browser doesn't add run any extra request except flight request. To check this you first check how many time that function is calling. I am very sure about this because I had the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, I checked my screens and got the issue.

Comment: @RahulGahlot can u share what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is a default browser feature. every time when you run a HTTP request your browser will run that twice one with a method you specified and other is for method OPTION where browser checks either that request is exist or not.