# Why is my HTTP get request being called multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have a Mat Dialog with an input field and some buttons and whenever I press one of those buttons I'm supposed to get the value inserted on the input field, retrieve some info from my database and send it to my component via a Service.

The problem is that whenever I click on the button, I'm executing several requests instead of just one.

The first request returns undefined and because of that my component isn't being populated with the values I want. 
The second request retrieves the values I want but because I'm already on my component, the info isn't being propagated via my Service.

Here is my code:

I'm assuming the service is working fine because I'm using it with two other components successfully.

#### my.service.ts

```
private ordersSource = new BehaviorSubject({});
currentOrders = this.ordersSource.asObservable();

private returnsSource = new BehaviorSubject({});
currentReturns = this.returnsSource.asObservable();

constructor() { }

setOrders(el){
  this.ordersSource.next(el);
}

setReturns(el){
  this.returnsSource.next(el);
}
```

In my mat dialog, I click a button that executes the createReturn(value) function. I already checked that the value is correct via debug so it is also correctly executing the else statement.

The getOrderByID and getOrderByNumber functions (called depending on the value) are being executed several times, however I can't see a reason why that is.

#### my-dialog.component.ts

```
private orders: {};
private returns: Return[] = [];

constructor(public rest: RestService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MyDialogComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any[],
    private myService: MyService, public dialog: MatDialog) { }

private createReturn(value) {
  if (value === undefined || value === "") {
    this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
  } else {
    this.getOrder(value);
    if (this.orders !== undefined) {
      this.router.navigate(['my-component']);
      this.closeDialog();
    }
  }
}

// Also working as expected, no problem detected here
private getOrder(value) {
  if (value.length > 0 && !isNaN(value)) {
    this.getOrderByID(value);
  } else if (value.length > 0 && isNaN(value)) {
    this.getOrderByNumber(value);
  }
  this.myService.setOrders(this.orders);
  this.myService.setReturns(this.returns);
}

private getOrderByID(value) {
  this.rest.getOrder(value).subscribe((orderIdData: {}) => {
    if (Object.entries(orderIdData).length !== 0) {
      this.orders = orderIdData;
      this.rest.getReturnByOrderId(value).subscribe((returnOrdIdData: Return[]) => {
        if (Object.entries(returnOrdIdData).length !== 0) {
          this.returns = returnOrdIdData;
        } else {
          this.returns = [];
        }
      }, error => {
        if (error.status === 404) {
          this.returns = [];
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
    }
  }, error => {
    this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
  });
}

private getOrderByNumber(value) {
  this.rest.getOrderByNumber(value).subscribe((orderNrData: {}) => {
    if (Object.entries(orderNrData).length !== 0) {
      this.orders = orderNrData;
      this.rest.getReturnByOrderNumber(value).subscribe((returnOrdNrData: Return[]) => {
        if (Object.entries(returnOrdNrData).length !== 0) {
          this.returns = returnOrdNrData;
        } else {
          this.returns = [];
        }
      }, error => {
        if (error.status === 404) {
          this.returns = [];
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
    }
  }, error => {
    this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
  });
}
```

And this is the component that router.navigate(['my-component']) redirects to. This component works as intended when I use the service in another component so I assume the problem isn't here.

#### my-component.component.ts

```
constructor(public rest: RestService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private myService: MyService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.currentOrders.subscribe(orderData => 
  this.setOrdersArray(orderData));
  this.myService.currentReturns.subscribe(returnData => 
  this.setReturnsArray(returnData));
  this.setOrderValues(this.orders);
  this.onChangeReturnType();
}
```

I tried debugging using Chrome's DevTools and I found out that the request was being executed three to six times when I only want it to be executed once.

[image]

Anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: this issue might arise because you haven't unsubscribe the currentOrder & currentReturns

Comment: You're saying that I have to unsubscribe to my service in my component? The problem is that even if I don't propagate the info I want to the service, the database request is still executing several times and only retrieves the info on the last request. If it retrieved on the first request everything would work fine...

Comment: Are you perhaps expecting an instant response from an async operation, here `this.getOrder(value); if (this.orders !== undefined) {`

Comment: Well, I'd like to call this.getOrder(value), assign the response to this.orders and propagate this.orders to my service... I want router.navigate to redirect me to my component ONLY when this.getOrder(value) successfully retrieves the info from the database. Is that instant response not possible? Do I have to use async await perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might want to know, here is the solution I found...
I finally understood and figured out what was the issue with my code.

Basically I was trying to send data to my service and navigate to my component before the database gave a response with the data I needed. Also, there were multiple http requests because of this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53371896/11033212.

So I made the following changes:

#### my-dialog.component.ts

```
private getData(value) {
  if (value === undefined || value === "") {
    this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
  } else {
    this.getOrder(value);
  }
}

private getOrder(value) {
  if (value.length > 0 && !isNaN(value)) {
    this.getOrderByID(value);
  } else if (value.length > 0 && isNaN(value)) {
    this.getOrderByNumber(value);
  }
}

private getOrderByID(value) {
  this.rest.getOrder(value).subscribe((orderIdData: {}) => {
    if (Object.entries(orderIdData).length !== 0) {
      this.orders = orderIdData;
      this.rest.getReturnByOrderId(value).subscribe((returnOrdIdData: Return[]) => {
        if (Object.entries(returnOrdIdData).length !== 0) {
          this.returns = returnOrdIdData;
        } else {
          this.returns = [];
        }
        this.createReturn(orderIdData);
      }, error => {
        if (error.status === 404) {
          this.returns = [];
        }
        this.createReturn(orderIdData);
      });
    } else {
      this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
    }
  }, error => {
    this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
  });
}

private getOrderByNumber(value) {
  this.rest.getOrderByNumber(value).subscribe((orderNrData: {}) => {
    if (Object.entries(orderNrData).length !== 0) {
      this.orders = orderNrData;
      this.rest.getReturnByOrderNumber(value).subscribe((returnOrdNrData: Return[]) => {
        if (Object.entries(returnOrdNrData).length !== 0) {
          this.returns = returnOrdNrData;
        } else {
          this.returns = [];
        }
        this.createReturn(orderNrData);
      }, error => {
        if (error.status === 404) {
          this.returns = [];
        }
        this.createReturn(orderNrData);
      });
    } else {
      this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
    }
  }, error => {
    this.inputForm.setErrors({ 'invalid': true });
  });
}

// This only happens after my database's response occurs
private createReturn(el) {
  this.setData(el);
  this.closeDialog();
  this.router.navigate(['my-component']);
}
```

My input field now calls getData() when a click event occurs.

Previously, I was calling the functions to close the dialog and to navigate to my component outside the getOrderByID and getOrderByNumber function requests. That lead the former functions to execute before the requests had a response.

With these changes, my code now waits for the database's response before continuing with its execution.